Got stuck at adding GPG key when installing Tor Repository on Debian
The official guide said,


Then add the gpg key used to sign the packages by running the following command at your command prompt:
wget -qO-
https://deb.torproject.org/torproject.org/A3C4F0F979CAA22CDBA8F512EE8CBC9E886DDD89.asc
| gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg>/dev/null



I run it with root privilege and got stuck. The asc file has been downloaded. But nothing happens after that. I try to run the rest two commands one by one but got no response. The cursor keeps blinking and that's all.

Well, check the file it was downloaded and processed into /usr/share/keyrings/tor-archive-keyring.gpg and you see no output because of >/dev/null redirection. The idea of that silent prompt is to make it suitable for a shell scripts. However - in case of the error - the error will be thrown and displayed. Looks like you're OK to go
